# mp4 video converted using ffmpeg works on safari 8 but wont play on safari

Tags: ios, html, video, safari, ffmpeg

The website I am working on has a video upload and play functionality which works like this :

1) Upload a video of any format it will converted to .mp4 format video using ffmpeg with following command

```
"ffmpeg -i <sourceRawPath> -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0    <destFullPath>
```

2) When I try to play these videos from website it works just fine on chrome and safari 8 but when i try to play these videos on safari 9 it show blank screen with following error in browsing console

> Failed to load resource: Plug-in handled load

Earlier the mp4 video would not even play on safari 8 but when we added -`profile:v baseline -level 3.0` to ffmpeg command now it works fine. We could not find solution for safari 9.

From java we are sending this response:

```
return Response.ok(video, "video/mp4").header("Aceept-Ranges", "bytes").cacheControl(cc).build();
```

`video --> video` file to be served.

Can anyone tell me what is the issue in this case?